Oauth2.0 Authorization code grant type what is the use case of State param
I want to know the use case of state passed for getting authorization code from Resource owner the sources says that its used to prevent CSRF attacks
can anyone explain how passing the random string as state will prevent that as if my request is intercepted in between by the attacker he will also get to know this passed state as well right?

The state parameter does not solve all problems, but is a CSRF protection. Eg if a malicious site tricks a user into clicking a link with an authorization code for another user it will be rejected:
https://www.example.com?code=abc&state=123

This might protect against exposing malicious resource server data to a victim. Consequences are not always obvious.
Preventing request interception has different (partial) protections, like TLS and PKCE. In some client environments you can even use proof of possession tokens to completely eliminate interception threats.
Yet in practice, eg for browser based apps, you typically cannot implement perfect security that fully prevents token interception. Therefore, always design access tokens to use least privilege and to be short lived.
